# DS-59 Triple-Split

Tags: display, dvi, splitter

Is it possible to split a [DMS-59](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59) to three (individual non-mirrored) DVI monitors? I haven't found any such cables available for purchase on the Internet. If not through a cable, how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that the DMS-59 only contains two sets of DVI pins I would not expect to be able to split it to three separate DVI connectors.  At most I would expect to see a DMS to two DVI connector cables.

In the image below the purplish colour is DVI2, and the light green is DVI1, I cannot find a third DVI.

[image]

If you want three monitors out of a graphics card then you will need to buy a card that specifically states support for three monitors.  Matrox have a series of devices that are specifically made for this such as their "[TripleHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/)" and I believe that high end ATi cards with [Eyefinity](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/Pages/eyefinity.aspx) can also drive three monitors as long as certain requirements are met.  I believe as long as you get a card with three display outputs (with at least one "DisplayPort") then you should be able to use 3 or more monitors.

ATi have a "[configurator](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/how-to/Pages/set-up.aspx)" to choose a graphics card that supports more monitors.

Nvidia cannot apparently do similar on their older (pre-500 series) cards as without buying a second graphics card as [this review](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2918/7) and their own page for the GTX480 seems to suggest:

> Use two GeForce GTX 480 cards in NVIDIA® SLI® configuration to project across three displays with NVIDIA 3D Vision Surround technology

Nvidias [3D Vision Surround Requirements](http://www.nvidia.com/object/3d-vision-surround-system-requirements.html) page only lists SLI systems as supporting more than two monitors.

If you only have a card with a DMS-59 output then you will only be able to split the output to two DVI connectors using a cable such as [this one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B000225EN4/ref=asc_df_B000225EN44528385?smid=A1WXJD44RPSKLO&tag=googlecouk06-21&linkCode=asn&creative=22218&creativeASIN=B000225EN4) which looks a little like this

[image]

Without fitting another graphics card into your computer or getting a card that supports more displays there is no way you will be able to drive more than two monitors.

Comment: Any ideas as to how I could connect three monitors with just one DMS connection? Are there any cables out there that split one DMS to two?

Comment: If you absolutely have to have the extra monitor but don't care about any high speed graphics performance, a USB DisplayLink adapter is probably the easiest choice (basically a one-port external video card).